# How to read in selective files (images) from a folder, where the search criteria is in a PandaFrame frame?

Tags: python, spyder

```
from PIL import Image 
import glob
import pandas as pd
```

This is the CSV file that I read in and filtered out...

```
Metadata = pd.read_csv('ISIC_2019_Training_GroundTruth.csv')

MelanomaData = Metadata.filter(["Images" ,"MEL"])
MelanomaData = MelanomaData[MelanomaData.MEL == 1]
```

The search criteria in the image column, the image ID is what I want to read in a folder (the folder has different images in there which I don't want to read in). The images are .jpg
[image]

I coded this to read in the images

```
image_list = []
for filename in (glob.glob('/Users/user/Documents/Final Year Proj/DATA/ISIC_2019_Training_Input/*.jpg')): 
    im=Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
    print(filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, you can simply extract the list of images from you dataframe and read them with your function:

```
image_name_list = MelanomaData['Images'].tolist()
path_string = '/Users/user/Documents/Final Year Proj/DATA/ISIC_2019_Training_Input/'
for image_name in image_name_list:
    im = Image.open(path_string + image_name + '.jpg')
    image_list.append(im)
```

Comment: Hi just a quick question what does image_name variable do??? in that context?

Comment: what do you mean "what does it do"? It is an iteration over a list of image names (from your df) and in each iteration the "current row" so, the current entry is put into the variable "image_name" and then used, to open the image

Comment: Yeah no worries i understand it, was just a bit confused

Comment: but im trying to read the images in a different way but im keep getting an error of NonType on my variable... i posted the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60020697/how-do-i-read-in-selective-image-files-from-a-folder-where-the-search-criteria?noredirect=1#comment106152031_60020697