# How to read in selective image files from a folder, where the search criteria is in a PandaFrame frame? Through cv2 in Python

Tags: python, opencv, spyder

```py
from PIL import Image 

import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os
```

The following is the filtering out the pandaframe:

```py
m = 3000
Metadata = pd.read_csv('ISIC_2019_Training_GroundTruth.csv')

MelanomaData = Metadata.filter(["image" ,"MEL"])
MelanomaData = MelanomaData[MelanomaData.MEL == 1] 
MelanomaData = MelanomaData[:-m]
```

When I tried to read in the image files I get `NoneType` in my variable explorer view:

```py
ImageList = []
ResizingImages = []
image_name_list  = MelanomaData['image'].tolist()
path_string = 'H:/My Documents/FYP/Skin Detection/ISIC_2019_Training_Input/'

datapath = os.path.join(path_string, '.jpg')

for files in datapath:    
    for image_name in image_name_list:
        img = cv2.imread(image_name)
        ImageList.append(img)
```

The search criteria is found in the image column:

```
    image                                MEL

2   ISIC_0000002                         1.0
4   ISIC_0000004                         1.0
12  ISIC_0000013                         1.0
21  ISIC_0000022_downsampled             1.0
```

This is the CSV file screenshot, but I only need the image and `MEL` columns, which is what I extracted, and displayed in the first section where I extracted and filtered that column:

[image]

[This is the link to the csv file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I8wxWn6oIzgHw8xcjK5LWi_z7gS6zv87QNnGNTi1Zbk/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Share a few lines of the .csv.

Comment: this is the whole program, do you mean you want to see the csv spreadsheet?

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: i have updated it !

Comment: It's a CSV, add it (or a relevant small section of it) as text as part of your question. It's unreasonable to expect others to first transcribe the image to a text file just to get started working out your problem.

Comment: i have! i have written the csv part in the structure of a pandaframe, and i have also inserted a screenshot of it in the link :)

Comment: i am so lostt, did i do something wrong?

Comment: I suppose the main issue is that in order for us to debug your issue, you need to provide a [mcve]. That also means you need to provide us the concrete input that allows us to reproduce the problem. The code you show reads a CSV in specific format. Assuming all the code is complete to reproduce the issue, we also need a sample CSV in valid format, that we can easily paste to our machine and reproduce the issue. When you just give us a screenshot of excel... that involves a lot of extra work, hence my request.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I8wxWn6oIzgHw8xcjK5LWi_z7gS6zv87QNnGNTi1Zbk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Let me know if you everyone can access that and if that is right

Comment: This question is off-topic, because it is reliant on an external link. Please remove the link to the Google Sheet and replace it with a CSV file, in the question, formatted using code formatting. This helps the question survive when the spreadsheet is finally deleted.